# Multilingual greeter object

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, node.js

After coming across Douglas Crockford's views on class-free OOP, and doing away with *new* and *this* in Javascript I tried defining an object with its own variable and function, and returning it in JSON, as shown below:

```
var newObj = function (name, lang){
    var obj = {
            "name":name,
            "greeter":greeter
    };
    return obj;
};

function greeter (lang){
        switch (lang){
                case "en":return "hi";
                case "es":return "hola";
                default: return "hello";
        }
}


//and finally, use the object    
var name = "john", lang = "es";  
var obj = newObj(name, lang);

console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.greeter(lang));
```

I know this code works in NodeJS, but I wonder if it is actually a good idea to do it this way. More specifically, are there any implications/consequences to returning functions within a javascript object that I should be aware of?

Comment: JSON cannot encode functions. I don't see you using JSON anywhere in that snippet.

Comment: `var obj = {
            "name":name,
            "greeter":greeter
    };` isn't that a JSON object?

Comment: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a data format based on the javascript [object initalizer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) syntax. Your code uses the object initalizer syntax json is based on, but it doesn't use json.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. So would it be more appropriate to phrase the question as Returning functions within javascript objects?

Comment: Is this real code from a project?  It looks more like example code.

Comment: it's something i just wrote after reading about crockford's views..

Comment: I am very curious to see whether this is actually efficient - since _nothing_ is really sharing any stuff, without prototypes, how does javascript optimise efficiently...?

Comment: it is not efficient. but the efficiency is going to matter only in applications where one needs to keep hundreds of objects in memory; for example a multiplayer online game, where each player's details will need to be stored in memory.

Comment: @Yogesch Ok, I know javascript is cool and such, but seriously, when did you saw an mmorpg made with javascript last time? BrowserQuest doesn't count, it was just a proof of concept.

Comment: exactly; which is why i think the memory efficiency gained from "true" oop doesn't matter in many cases..

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON. However JSON was inspired from Javascript Native way of creating object. This is why they're really similar.

However JSON handles only data, not functions.

Furthermore you can rewrite your function like this :

```
function newObj(name){
    this.name = name;
    return this;
};
newObj.prototype.greeter = function(lang){
    switch (lang){
            case "en":return "hi "+this.name;
            case "es":return "hola "+this.name;
            default: return "hello "+this.name;
    }
}

var obj = new newObj("name");
obj.greeter("de");
```

As you can see

1. I got rid of the 2nd parameter in the newObj function since it was not used.
2. I bind greeter to the Object so now I can use this.name in greeter to greet you by your name.
3. If you try to JSONify this, everything under prototype will be ignored so you won't have any error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```js
var newObj = function(name, lang) {
  var obj = {
    name: name,
    greeter: function(lang) {
      switch (lang) {
        case "en":
          return "hi";
        case "es":
          return "hola";
        default:
          return "hello";
      }
    }
  };

  return obj;
};


/* and finally, use the object */
var name = "john", lang = "es";

var obj = newObj(name, lang);    

console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.greeter(lang));
```

As you returned property in the same way you can return function too;

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's a normal practice. Just be wary of function scope, functions declared outside of your object might not accessible.

Comment: Or did you mean Javascript objects instead like an associative arrays/hash that has key/value pairs?

Comment: yeah, javascript objects. thanks. is the code I posted okay to use in a real system?

Comment: Yes, pretty much just be wary of function scope. Functions declared outside of your object might not accessible.

Comment: thanks. might i suggest to make this part of your answer since it answers the question directly.